# Why does Math.tan() return different values for different levels of precision?

Tags: java, trigonometry

I'm in the middle of testing a program that reads mathematical input, and calculates the answer according to order of operations. I've come across a problem. When calculating the tangent of `Math.PI / 2`, it returns the value `1.633123935319537E16`.

However, somewhere along the way in my program, that value can get shortened to `1.5707964`, instead of `1.5707963267948966`. When I call `Math.tan(1.5707964)`, it returns a value of `-1.3660249798894601E7`.

I'm not asking for help in figuring out the shortening, but rather, I want to understand the divergent answers, and any other things I should watch out for when calculating trigonometric functions.

Comment: It would be helpful to share your code and produce an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "I'm not asking for help in figuring out the shortening" But I guess it's because you're assigning it to a `float` somewhere.

Comment: "any other things I should watch out for when calculating trigonometric functions." Not just about trigonometric functions, but any floating point calculation: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Do you know the theoretical value of tan(pi/2)?

Comment: @Charlie note that `[mcve]` is a handy shortcut for this link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to understand the divergent answers

- `tan(π/2)` is undefined
- `tan(π/2 - tiny amount)` is very large in magnitude and positive
- `tan(π/2 + tiny amount)` is very large in magnitude and negative

The numbers that you are passing in are not exactly `π/2`:

- `1.5707963267948966192313216...` is *slightly more* precise value of `π/2` (calculated [here](http://ideone.com/GHqnmH); more decimal places aren't necessary to illustrate the point).
- `1.5707963267948966` is just smaller
- `1.5707964` is just larger.

To illustrate, here is graph from [Math Is Fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-sin-cos-tan-graphs.html):
[image: x]

Comment: Andy, hope you're ok with me adding illustration.